# Grouping matching names with totals Firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I did a basic Firebird Report to call on all debtors and transactions
The report looks as follows

---

```
SELECT 
POSPAY.TXNO,
DEBTORS.COMPANY,
POSPAY.AMOUNT,
POSINVTRANS.TXDATE
FROM
POSPAY
INNER JOIN DEBTORS ON (POSPAY.ACCTNUMBER = DEBTORS.ACCOUNT)
INNER JOIN POSINVTRANS ON (POSPAY.TXNO = POSINVTRANS.TXNO)
WHERE
PAYMNTTYPID = '7' 
and  
weekly = :weekly and
txdate >= :fromdate and
txdate <= :todate
```

---

This works correctly and gives me output on Debtor Name, TXNO, TXDATE, AMOUNT

I now want to write a similar report but need to group the debtors and give totals on the transactions ie I need the output Debtor name (If JOHN is twice, need to list once), Total ammount (Sum of John's transactions)

I still need innerjoin on debtors but no longer on posinvtrans, I was thinking it should look something like

```
SELECT 
POSPAY.TXNO,
DEBTORS.COMPANY,
POSPAY.AMOUNT

FROM
POSPAY
INNER JOIN DEBTORS ON (POSPAY.ACCTNUMBER = DEBTORS.ACCOUNT)

WHERE
PAYMNTTYPID = '7' 
and  
weekly = :weekly and
txdate >= :fromdate and
txdate <= :todate

Group by DEBTORS.COMPANY
```

but no luck, get errors on Group by
'*invalid expression in the select list (not containing in either an aggregate function  or the GROUP BY CLAUSE)*'
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of fields in the select list have to be either also listed in the `group by` list or be aggregate functions like `count(*)`, `max(amount)`, etc.

The problem is that you have not told Firebird what to do with `POSPAY.TXNO` and `POSPAY.AMOUNT` and it is not sufficient to tell what you do want to happen to them.

I suggest you remove those 2 fields from the query and have a select list of `DEBTORS.COMPANY`, `sum(POSPAY.AMOUNT)` as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick Upson, the report works exactly like i wanted it

Answer (score 0):

If you use `GROUP BY` you either need to include a column in the `GROUP BY`, or apply an aggregate function on the column. In your example you need to leave out `POSPAY.TXNO`, as that is transaction specific (or you could use the aggregate function `LIST`), and you need to apply the aggregate function `SUM` to `AMOUNT` to get the total:

```sql
SELECT 
DEBTORS.COMPANY,
SUM(POSPAY.AMOUNT)

FROM
POSPAY
INNER JOIN DEBTORS ON (POSPAY.ACCTNUMBER = DEBTORS.ACCOUNT)

WHERE
PAYMNTTYPID = '7' 
and  
weekly = :weekly and
txdate >= :fromdate and
txdate <= :todate

Group by DEBTORS.COMPANY
```